# Let recursiveness in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, infinite, let

Could someone explain the behaviour of this little piece of code with the following input: `[[1,2],[3,4]]`?

```
infiniteList ls = let v = ls ++ v
                  in concat v
```

The result is an infinite list but I don't realise why. I've understood that the trick is in:

```
ls ++ v
```

But how exactly work the let since we do not define the initial value for the variable `v`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To evaluate `v`, just replace it with its definition:

```
v = ls ++ v
  = ls ++ ls ++ v
  = ls ++ ls ++ ls ++ v
  = ls ++ ls ++ ls ++ ls ++ v
  = ls ++ ls ++ ls ++ ls ++ ls ++ v
  = ls ++ ls ++ ls ++ ls ++ ls ++ ls ++ v
```

Clearly this will never end.

Comment: And the evaluation happens when the function concat is called, right?

Comment: @BigMeister Because Haskell is lazy, this evaluation occurs only when it is absolutely necessary, such as when you print out the result of calling `infiniteList`.

Comment: Don't think of `ls ++ v` as constructing a value that is then assigned to `v`; rather, it is just a *rule* for evaluating `v`. "When you see `v`, replace it with `ls ++ v`." Whether then recursive occurrence of `v` needs to be evaluated depends on the consumer of the original `v`.

Comment: Yes, I got it now! I was misunderstanding the meaning of the let but now It is clear. Thank you both!